# How do I get to the top of the room with the frost boss after killing him?

Tags: valdis-story-abyssal-city

Above where I'm standing is a key thing that I think opens the door directly to the right of me:

[image]

During the battle, I was able to get up there using the ice blocks created by the boss, but now that the boss is dead there are no more ice blocks. How can I get up there so that I can unlock the door and progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Killing the boss should have given you a new set of magic powers: Ice.

Using the **down** Ice magic (Ice Tower), you can create your own ice blocks to stand on.  Head to the left, near the door where you came in, and climb up on one to get up to the top.